# Equivalent definition of decomposable map

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras

Let $A\subset B(H)$ be an operator system and $B$ be a $C^*$-algebra. (1)$u:A\rightarrow B$ is called a decomposable map if $u$ is in the linear span of $CP(A, B)$, where $CP(A,B)$ is the set of all completely positive maps from $A$ to $B$.

There is another equivalent definition. (2)$u:A\rightarrow B$ is called a decomposable map if $u=u_1-u_2+i(u_3-u_4)$, each $u_i\in CP(A,B)(i=1,\cdots 4) $

It is easy to see that (2) implies (1). How to check that (1) imply (2)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $u:A\to B$ is decomposable, and write $u=\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_ku_k$ for some $\lambda_k\in\mathbb C$ and $u_k\in CP(A,B)$.  Each $\lambda_k$ can be written $\lambda_k=(\lambda_{k,1}-\lambda_{k,2})+i(\lambda_{k,3}-\lambda_{k,4})$, where $\lambda_{k,j}\geq0$ for $k=1,\ldots,n$, $j=1,\ldots,4$.  Then for each $j$, $\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{k,j}u_k$ is in $CP(A,B)$, and we have 
$$u=\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{k,1}u_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{k,2}u_k\right)+i\left(\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{k,3}u_k-\sum_{k=1}^n\lambda_{k,4}u_k\right).$$

Comment: I know the fact every element $a$ in a $C^*$-algebra can be decomposed as following $a=a_1+ia_2$,  where $a_1,a_2\in A_{sa}$. $a_i =a_i^{+}-a_i^{-}(i=1,2)$,. I don't undersatnd why every completely positive map can be decomped similarly.

Comment: Sorry, I misread.  Completely positive maps are the "positive elements" here, they can't be decomposed further in this fashion.

Comment: So the above answer is not correct?

Comment: No, I misread the statement of your comment.  Why would you think the answer is wrong?

Comment: You mentioned that compeletely positive maps are "positive elements", they cannot be decomposed further. Why can we decompose each $\lambda _k$ into the form of $ \lambda_k=(\lambda_{k,1}-\lambda_{k,2})+i(\lambda_{k,3}-\lambda_{k,4})$?

Comment: You're thinking about this too hard.  If $u$ is CP, then $u$ is a sum of CP maps.  And for the second question, if $\lambda=5-3i$, then $\lambda=(5-0)+i(0-3)$

Comment: I am so stupid, I viewd $\lambda$ as c.p maps. They are complex numbers.

Comment: That makes sense (not that you're stupid, but the confusion).